# Как определить одну специализацию шаблона для фундаментальных типов и другую для пользовательских

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Мне нужно чтобы функция бы при передаче ей фундаментальных типов исполняла один код, а при передаче пользовательских типов поведение отличалось. Прочитал про `std::is_fundamental` но он вызывается уже в коде и у меня функция не скомпилируется если буду делать такие проверки так как в шаблонной функции присутствуют вызовы методов каких нет у простых типов, как это можно определять прямо при инстанциации?

Comment: еще один вопрос про трейты и `if constexpr`?

Comment: @user7860670 видимо, как загуглить это можно? а что то не могу найти

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206860/%d0%a4%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd/1206865#1206865

Comment: как уже упоминалось, можно использовать `if constexpr`, однако это только в том случае, если вы используете 17-ый стандарт и выше. Иначе используйте `std::enable_if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если компилятор поддерживает 17 стандарт, тогда просто

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void show(T t)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_fundamental<T>::value) {
        std::cout << "fund\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "non\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    show(1);
    std::string s;
    show(s);
}
```

Если компилятор постарше (подреврее), то можно где то так (гуглить SFINAE)

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type show(T t)
{
std::cout << "fund\n";
}


template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type show(T t)
{
std::cout << "non\n";
}
```

Comment: спасибо! можете пожалуйста подсказать в реальной работе часто это пригождается и где бы эту тему посоветовали изучить?

Comment: для начала нужно понять, когда нужны шаблоны. А они логически возникают каждый раз, когда хочется сделать что то как в javascript/perl/python - duck typing - утиная типизация, а базовый класс вводить не хочется/нет возможности. Но потом хочется сделать небольшую логику на базе того, какой именно тип прилетел. Теперь, когда есть if constexpr и концепты, SFINAE уже отходит на второй план. Хотите знать шаблоны глубже - ищите книгу "Шаблоны C++. Справочник разработчика 2-е издание. Дэвид Вандевурд, Николаи М. Джосаттис, Дуглас Грегор"